# Shouldn't rndc reload invalidate the cache of that domain?

Tags: cache, bind, rndc

I've got a nameserver that I updated a zone file on, incremented the serial, and ran `rndc reload`. I then verified that `named` saw it in the log, and it did, without errors. But when I run `dig domain.tld @localhost` *note: @localhost is the bind server I made the changes on*. bind still see's the old A record, in its cache. Do I misunderstand how bind works? or is this a problem?

Comment: So I sorta figured this one out... upon further investigation by a co-working some ACL or something was preventing the query and thus we were getting a cached result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [BIND Administrator's Reference Manual](http://www.isc.org/software/bind/documentation), *reload* reloads configuration files and zones. Only. Verify that you get the response from the correct nameserver.

Comment: well considering localhost is the nameserver and I did it `@localhost`. so according to the manual it wouldn't clear the cache for that zone, if I understand what you're saying correctly?

Comment: It does not cache information for master zones. There is something wrong with either your named.conf (is it declared as a master zone?) or with the SOA and/or NS RRs of your zone.

Comment: I don't remember, don't think so, it was probably a cpanel addon domain. We never edit named.conf. I know it was only an A record for a subdomain that I had updated.

Comment: Are we talking about your domain? For if we are, I see that it is delegated as a CNAME which makes it impossible to delegate any other information with it: http://zytrax.com/books/dns/ch8/cname.html - Can you post the relevant contents of the named.conf and the zone file? Even though you do not directly edit them.

Comment: no we're not talking about my domain, and I couldn't post it. It's a customers domain at my job. tbh, I don't even know what account it is anymore, that was days ago. But I suspect the server was caching stuff it shouldn't have been.